# Batch File Text string extract and join

Tags: batch-file

I would like to be able to loop through the sections of a text file and extract & concatenate parts of 2 lines in each section.
An small example of the text file content:

**Text File Content**

```
Fmt ID_FMT_JE_EVT ( 3 ; 18 ) struct
{
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_DATE ( 3 ; 12 ) date 11/12/2015 20:13:24
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ( 3 ; 14 ) uint 1476
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_INDEX ( 3 ; 15 ) uint 6
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_ETAT ( 3 ; 16 ) uint 1
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_PARAM ( 3 ; 17 ) string ""
}
Fmt ID_FMT_JE_EVT ( 3 ; 18 ) struct 
{
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_DATE ( 3 ; 12 ) date 11/12/2015 20:16:15
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ( 3 ; 14 ) uint 1801
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_INDEX ( 3 ; 15 ) uint 5
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_ETAT ( 3 ; 16 ) uint 1
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_PARAM ( 3 ; 17 ) string ""
}
Fmt ID_FMT_JE_EVT ( 3 ; 18 ) struct 
{
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_DATE ( 3 ; 12 ) date 11/12/2015 20:13:45
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ( 3 ; 14 ) uint 1461
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_INDEX ( 3 ; 15 ) uint 99
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_ETAT ( 3 ; 16 ) uint 1
    Fmt ID_FMT_JE_PARAM ( 3 ; 17 ) string ""
}
```

What I'm after is to be able to look inside each of the sections, find the lines named 
**ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM** & **ID_FMT_JE_INDEX**, combine the values associated with them (separated with a hyphen if poss) into a single variable and display them as a list.

For example, taking the first section of the text file example above, I'm trying to extract the following..

```
Fmt ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ( 3 ; 14 ) uint 1476
Fmt ID_FMT_JE_INDEX ( 3 ; 15 ) uint 6
```

..grab the values from each line..

```
1476
6
```

..join them into a single variable (preferably separated with a hyphen)..

```
1476-6
```

..before moving onto the next section and repeating the process until the end of the file. 
Then I would like to display the results as a list:

**Desired Result**

```
1476-6
1801-5
1461-99
```

I have absolutely no idea on where to start on this, my tech level is pretty low - I'm able to find my way around batch files, and can tweak to suit, but not write from scratch.
Thanks in advance to anyone who takes a look at this.

Comment: Can you include what code you've written so far?

Comment: I would love to - I have grabbed several examples of code elswhere on stackoverflow to try to do this, but I don't have enough know-how to 'tweak' it enough to get it to do what I want. So unfortunately I don't have any..

Comment: If you can include any code you have tried and why it didn't work for you it would be really helpful for others who may be able to help you further.

Comment: This is what I have been fiddling with, unfortunately without much success:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900374/find-and-extract-text-from-within-existing-text-file/8905642#8905642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. Change soinput.txt to whatever your text file name is.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM="
set "ID_FMT_JE_INDEX="
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-9 delims= " %%G IN ('type soinput.txt ^|findstr "ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ID_FMT_JE_INDEX"') DO (
    SET %%H=%%O
    IF DEFINED ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM (
        IF DEFINED ID_FMT_JE_INDEX (
            ECHO !ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM!-!ID_FMT_JE_INDEX!
            set "ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM="
            set "ID_FMT_JE_INDEX="
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Output

```
1476-6
1801-5
1461-99
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Perfect!
Thanks @Squashman!
That works brilliantly. Thanks for taking the time out to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below use an advanced trick. In your result you want the token number 9 of the search lines, like `1476` the first time and `6` the second one, but the first time you want to insert a dash after the token and the second time a CR+LF (line terminator). This way, we may define two "End Of Token" strings and just exchange they each time that a token 9 is displayed. Each token-EOT pair is displayed via `set /P "=..." < NUL` command, because `echo` always insert a CR+LF at end.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "eot1=-"
rem Define "eot2" as CR+LF pair:
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set eot2=%%a^
%empty line 1/2, don't remove%
%empty line 2/2, don't remove%

for /F "tokens=9" %%a in ('findstr "ID_FMT_JE_NUMALM ID_FMT_JE_INDEX" input.txt') do (
   set /P "=%%a!eot1!" < NUL
   set "eot=!eot1!" & set "eot1=!eot2!" & set "eot2=!eot!"
)
```

This method run faster than other methods that perform more operations in each iteration. If the file to process is large, the difference in processing time may be significant.